# How to visualize events/signals in Django project?

Tags: django, uml, diagram

When project gets bigger I need to see all events which happens during model or project lifecycle.

**EDIT**
*I don't want `Django` to generate some diagram, I want to do it manually.*

I want to see (on graph or chart) all consequences of actions like creating, updating, saving etc.

For example, when I create a `Property` object, there is a `post_save` signal which creates `PropertyProfile` and `PropertyProfile` has overriden `save` method where I calculate price of the property before `super().save(..)`.

Which tool should I use to visualize such events so I can see what will happen and when will it happen?

I think that `sequence diagram` or `flowchart` is probably not enough because I can't visualize all such information but maybe I'm wrong, not good at UML.

Answer (score 1):

to achieve this ,you first need to generate data; write log or define a model, create instance when signal fired;

to visualize such data .It almostly depends on how many data there.

ELK is suitable if you have large large amount data;otherwise , Echarts maybe is enough